# pointers in C with a #define

Tags: c, microcontroller, avr, winavr

The function:

```
#define ASSOC(port) (*(volatile bit_field *) (&port))
```

The function call:

```
#define SCLK ASSOC(PORTC).bit0
```

bit_field defined as a struct like this:

```
typedef struct {
 unsigned char bit0 :1, bit1 :1, bit2 :1, bit3 :1, bit4 :1, bit5 :1,
   bit6 :1, bit7 :1;
} bit_field;
```

I don't know where &port is defined.

Can someone please explain how the function is read and how it works please? I am not very good with pointers and this example in particular is very confusing with "*" in the front and at the end and the "&" with the port.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`port` is not defined. It is the argument to ASSOC as you can see here:

```
#define ASSOC(port) /* etc. */
```

Also, I assume it is supposed to be a `char`, because the `bit_field` has 8 bits. The `&` in `&port` simply serves to get its address in memory.

ASSOC in turn casts `&port` to a `volatile bit_field *` and then there is the extra `*` at the beginning to point directly to the contents of the resulting pointer.

Therefore, once you call ASSOC(port), you can use it as a bit_field type structure. For example, the `SCLK` macro will give the first bit of `PORTC`.

Comment: This took me a while to understand but I get it now. The most confusing part to me was why he was he was defining bit_field as a pointer variable (with the *). It is because he is getting all the contents of the typedef bit_field that he created. Then he deferences the whole thing [(*(volatile bit_field *) (&port))] with the outside * because if he doesn't, he will return the address of what he is passing in (PORTC). So he deferences the whole thing so the contents are returned and not the address.... I am finally understanding pointers better :)

Answer (score 2):

The `ASSOC` macro you define is an in-place cast.

1. You pass in a value `port` (in this case, it's coming from the other macro `SCLK`)
2. `ASSOC` takes the address of `port` with the `&` operator
3. `ASSOC` casts `port`'s address to a `(volatile bit_field *)`
4. `ASSOC` [dereferences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator) (`*`s) the address of the `bit_field`

The result is the same bits as you started with, but usable as a `bit_field` struct.

Comment: This took me a while to understand but I get it now. The most confusing part to me was why he was he was defining bit_field as a pointer variable (with the *). It is because he is getting all the contents of the typedef bit_field that he created. Then he deferences the whole thing [(*(volatile bit_field *) (&port))] with the outside * because if he doesn't, he will return the address of what he is passing in (PORTC). So he deferences the whole thing so the contents are returned and not the address.... I am finally understanding pointers better :)

Answer (score 1):

`ASSOC` takes what I'm assuming is a `char` named `PORTC` and gives back a `bit_field` with the same values as each individual bit in `PORTC`.

`SCLK` returns one of the bits in the bit field.

You're taking `PORTC` and passing it to `ASSOC` as the parameter.